# what does happen if size of MappedByteBuffer is more than file length while doing FileChannel.map()

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to map a randomaccessfile to memory and then want to append some data .
    `MappedByteBuffer buffer = file.getChannel().map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, size);`

what does happen if the `size > file.length`?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is in the Javadoc:

> The behavior of this method when the requested region is not
>   completely contained within this channel's file is unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it but..

If the end of the memory mapping is beyond the existing end of the file, it will grow the file.

If you can't access the file as READ_WRITE you will get an Exception regardless of the size.

Comment: In which case you will have an Exception. I am assuming the READ_WRITE would be successful if the size were the length and the OP wants to know what would happen if the size were greater than the length.

Comment: You can't assume anying. The behaviour is specifically unspecified.

Comment: @EJP Never the less that is what it does on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Today. In this version. Until they change it. Or the operating system changes its mind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Java 8 on Mac, and it raises `java.io.IOException: Channel not open for writing - cannot extend file to required size`.

If there is no particular reason to allocate more than the file size, you can always use a ternary to quickly select the smaller one.